# Change value on 11th column based on 9th column using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text file that has a white space separated values. Column 9th has field that needs to be matched(ice), but column 11th needs substitution based on the match. Example :

```
    a b c d e f g h ice j k l m
```

Intended output :

```
    a b c d e f g h ice j keep l m
```

I'm trying use this :

```
    sed -i -r 's/ice [^ ]*/ice keep/' test.log
```

But it give this :

```
    a b c d e f g h ice keep k l m
```

Please help me. I'm not familiar with sed and regex.

Comment: `sed -i -r 's/ice\( [^ ]*\)/ice\1 keep/' test.log` to keep internal content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more suitable for `awk` or any other tool that understands *columns*:

```
awk '{if ($9=="ice") {$11="keep"} print}' inputfile
```

Fields in awk are delimited by space by default.  `$9` would denote the 9<sup>th</sup> field.  If the 9<sup>th</sup> field is `ice`, change the 11<sup>th</sup> to `keep`.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
a b c d e f g h ice j keep l m
```

---

You could do it using `sed` too, but it's not quite straight-forward:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^ ]+ ){8}ice \S+ )(\S+)/\1keep/' inputfile
```

Here `([^ ]+ ){8}` would match the first 8 fields.  `(([^ ]+ ){8}ice \S+ )` matches 10 fields with the 9<sup>th</sup> being `ice` and captures it into a group that is substituted later making use of a backreference, `\1`.

Comment: You can simplify it some: `awk '$9=="ice" {$11="keep"}1'`

Comment: @Jotne I deliberately chose an explicit conditional in order to make things more clear given that it might not be obvious to the OP.  Perhaps I'll replace `1` with an explicit `print` too.

Comment: Thanks @devnull awk and sed works like a charm, from my understanding awk cant modified original file streamline and sed works with -i. Correct me if i wrong.

Comment: @user2469038 `awk` versions 4.1.0 and higher support _in-place_ editing too.  Refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html

Comment: @devnull Thanks for the info, really appreciates it. Thumbs up for u. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^((\S+\s+){8}ice\s+\S+\s)\S+/s//\1keep/' file
```

This matches the 9th non-spaced value to `ice` and then changes the 11th non-spaced value to `keep`.

Answer (score 0):

in your sample it work but it does not take count of column number, do you realy need the column reference or just the content ?

```
sed '/ice/ s/k/keep/' YourFile
```